# What is an open sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

What is an open sphere? I recently came across this phrase in [these](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~neubrand/notes.pdf) notes on complex analysis (pg. 12, Lemma 2.1.3).

I know what an open ball is, but this phrase is confusing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Looks like they think at an "open disk" (or "open ball") when they call for "$D \subset \Bbb C$ an open sphere"

Comment: I'd assume it's a sphere, not counting the surface. That is, it's the set of points _inside_ the sphere. But I might be wrong. EDIT: No, that doesn't seem to make sense in context; it has to be 2D, right?

Comment: $D \subset \Bbb C$ and they consider rectangles $R \subset D$ in the same Lemma (so I think my first comment was appropriated).

Comment: @Surb- Yes but what is the nature of D? Is it an open disc? Is it a circle? What?

Comment: The notes have disappeared so we may never get an answer what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we have to set in mind that mathematicians frequently use *metaphors* to construct their notions, which broadly means similes based on similarity (I highly recommend you to search the Aristotle 's opera *Poetics* and *Rhetoric* about metaphor).

We can ground our thought on $\Bbb R^3$ (the $3-d$ Euclidean space with the common coördinate system), where a *ball* is geometrically a sphere-bounded solid. Thus an *open ball* is the rest of a ball without the sphere (~the "spheric shell"), and as a set can be defined via $B_ε(a):= \{x\in\Bbb R^3| \|x-a\|<ε\}$, where $a$ is the centre, $ε>0$ the radius and $\|.\|$ the euclidean norm in $\Bbb R^3$. Now we can metaphorically speak about balls of $\Bbb R^n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and extend the notion of ball with the well written set discription.

With the above geometric thought we derive that a sphere can be described as $S_ε(a):= \{x\in\Bbb R^n| \|x-a\|=ε\}$, namely the boundary of ball, so $S_ε(a)=\partial B_ε(a)$. *But* it is common in topology, real and complex analysis to use the name *sphere* or *ball* indifferently about the interior of a euclidean sphere, so -with our symbols- the open ball is the set $B_ε(a)$ and it has boundary the spheric shell $\partial B_ε(a)$ (and of course it can be arbitrarily represented as $S_ε(a), \partial S_ε(a)$).

Finally a more neutral term is the one of *open neighbourhood*, which can be defined as our open ball/open sphere. The notion of open neighbourhood is broader, for an author can use it to extend the notion of a open interval from $\Bbb R$ to every $\Bbb R^n$ (or even broader it can be used to denote just *open sets*). In this case we will get the interiors of euclidean *parallelograms* in $\Bbb R^2$ or *parallelepipeds* in $\Bbb R^3$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

They must mean an open ball/disc, it's the only thing that makes sense here.

I agree though that the use of the word sphere is a bit confusing, in my mind an open sphere would be the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid |x-a|<\varepsilon\}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\varepsilon>0$ a real number (which makes no sense in the context of this lemma). Similarly an open **disc** for me is an open ball in 2 dimensions (either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}$).